# Castle Windsor auto registration of multiple interfaces and their corresponding implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

If I have the following setup:

```
public interface IUsersQuery{}

public class UsersQuery : IUsersQuery {}

public interface ICompanyQuery{}

public class CompanyQuery : ICompanyQuery {}
```

Is it possible to auto register all the IABCQuery and its corresponding implementation ABCQuery in one shot instead of doing one by one:

```
container.Regsiter(
  Component.For<ICompanyQuery>().ImplementedBy<CompanyQuery>(),
  Component.For<IUsersQuery>().ImplementedBy<UsersQuery>()
)
```

I was thinking maybe if i add some sort of marker to the interfaces,

```
public interface IEnhancedQuery {}

public interface IUsersQuery : IEnhanceQuery {}

public interface ICompanyQuery : IEnhancedQuery {}
```

then I may be able to do it, but I'm having a hard time coming up with the way to register them all with auto registration through AllTypes.

```
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IEnhancedQuery>());
        var iQueries = container.ResolveAll<IEnhancedQuery>();
        foreach (IEnhancedQuery p in iQueries)
        {
            var actualInterface = // how to get the actual interface type of p;

            // would the following work?
            container.Register(Component.For(actualInterface)
              .ImplementedBy(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(actualInterface)
              .WithService.FirstInterface()));
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromThisAssembly()
      .Where(Component.IsInTheSameNamespaceAs<IUsersQuery>())
      .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
      .LifestyleTransient()
);
```

[The documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md) details all the options.

Comment: Got it working with this:                  `container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IEnhancedQuery().WithService.FromInterface().Configure(c=>c.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)));`  Then IUsersQuery --> UsersQuery in the container.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically name them by their concrete type ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether Castle has auto registration feature but you can implement one using reflection.

It doesn't seem a very hard task to do :

1.Find all the interfaces that their name end with Query

2.Check to see if there's a Type available for this interface according to your rule

3.If the type exists register the component.